# Kubernetes Volume mountpath

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm running multiple web pods for the same application and I have this folder in my application where clients can upload their files.
the folder is sitting in this directory(if my war file name is sample.war) /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/sample/uploadfiles and I want it to be shared between all the web pods, 
in case the client login to a random session within a specific web POD 1 and upload some files there, can find them next time he logs in to another random session within another web POD N 
I'm using Google Cloud Platform container engine and Google persistent disk as persistent volume

my dockerfile looks something like this

```
FROM tomcat:8-jre8
ADD sample.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

I have this in my Kubernetes Deployment YAML file

```
volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/
```

but I get an empty /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ directory inside my pod with only lost+found and even when I mountpath any sub-directory of /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ that sub-directory is empty too.

So should I edit my application in a way the files gets uploaded to a directory outside /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ like /usr/local/tomcat/uploadfiles, or there is a way to share /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/sample/uploadfiles between the pods.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing the same writeable volume between different pods is not something that is supported by all volume types. Have a read of the [Persistent Volumes manual](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/) and look for volume types that support `ReadWriteMany`

Comment: I changed the uploadfiles folder location and it's working fine now thanks for your help

Comment: What folder location did U give? Should it be outside of /usr ?